# Tomboy Notes panel no longer shows note titles after upgrade from Lucid to Maverick

Tags: 10.10, indicator, tomboy

In Lucid, Tomboy Notes had a panel icon that, when clicked on, would show a list of the most recent notes. You could click the little pushpin icon next to a title to make it show up all the time, no matter how many notes had been added after it.

Since upgrading to Maverick, the icon no longer displays the note titles, so I have no way of knowing which note I'm clicking on. Any ideas on how to fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is due to [a bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/tomboy/+bug/627744) with the notification area fallback of the new Tomboy indicator. You'll see the fallback if you've removed the indicator applet that hosts application indicators from your panel. To see note titles until it's fixed, you can either add "Indicator Applet" back to your panel, or use Tomboy as an applet.

Comment: Nope, it does pinning, it just doesn't display the note titles.

Comment: Then you've removed the indicator applet and what you're seeing is the notification area fallback. Updating my answer to reflect that.

Comment: Nope, the indicator applet is on my panel. I shut down Tomboy and added it separately as an applet, and it does work correctly now. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

This is [a bug](https://bugs.edge.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/tomboy/+bug/627744) that's only been fixed recently. It will be published through an update, you can subscribe to that bug to follow its progress.

Comment: Thanks, that's exactly what's happening. I've subscribed to the bug report.

Answer (score 0):

If you can't wait for the stable version to get the fix, and dislike indicator applet, the fix is already in the PPA. Do the following

```
sudo apt-add-repository ppa:tomboy-packagers/development
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install tomboy
```

Source: https://edge.launchpad.net/~tomboy-packagers/+archive/development